# MongoDB initialize failed, DuplicateKey

Tags: c++, mongodb

i want to use MongoDB from my C++ application, I've downloaded the MongoDb binary Version 3.0.5 and the legacy C++ Driver Version 1.0.5 from Git and installed both.

I followed the [instruction](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Configuring%20the%20Legacy%20Driver) with this code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <mongo/bson/bson.h>
#include <mongo/client/dbclient.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  mongo::Status status = mongo::client::initialize();

 return 0;
}
```

After Compile and Run i get to following message:

```
Attempt to add global initialiser failed, status: DuplicateKey GlobalLogManager Abort
```

Some ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same behavior when using legacy driver compiled for C++03 (default) and application code compiled with C++11/C++14. It always segfaults and sometimes writes the same message (depending optimization level). See the related bug on [mongo website](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-372).

The solution is to either:

- compile your code with C++03 (`-std=c++03`)
- recompile the driver with C++11 support.

For the C++11 support in driver, simply pass `--c++11=on` to `scons`.

```
scons --c++11=on install
```

*Tested with GCC 4.9.1*